# What purpose built functions (besides nurseries) do the alien hive structures perform?

Tags: alien-franchise

As we have seen in the film franchise, Xenomorphes are constantly building onto the resin hives that house thier egg nurseries.

What other specific purposes are demonstrated in thier architecture?

Comment: Typo: thier -> their.